# replace MYSQL string using a PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, string, replace

I have this code and couldn't get it to work:

```
$character_set_array = array();

    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 8, 'characters' => '0123456789');
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($character_set_array as $character_set) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set['count']; $i++) {
            $temp_array[] = $character_set['characters'][rand(0, strlen($character_set['characters']) - 1)];
        }
    }
    shuffle($temp_array);
    $pinstart = 'AA';
    $pinend = implode('', $temp_array);
    $newpin = $pinstart.$pinend;




function regenerate_pin($pin)
{   
    if ($PIN == 'PIN') { return ''; } else {
    $pin = mysql_real_escape_string($pin);  // SECURITY!
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1");



    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        return 'This pin has already been used';
            } else {
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE pins SET pins='$newpin'"); 
        return "The pin has been regened, the new pin is '.$newpin.'";
             } }
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to get it to do is this:
 - Get the pin from a HTML input box, 
 - Check if the pin exists in the database (works)
 - If it exists, replace $pin with $newpin and print out the $newpin, this is how my table looks like

[image]

- Some info about my table:
- Table name = pins Column where pin is stored is named Pin

Thank you for reading and I hope I find a quick solution.

Comment: This will fail with PINs that start with "0".

Comment: Shouldn't it be if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) { because if there is a record there then it is in use otherwise it is a new pin.

Comment: I already have a script that checks if the string exists everything is working fine @jeff so I don't think its a problem

Comment: @ignacio vazquez-abrams I make it start with AA

Comment: Then I'm very not surprised that your queries don't work. Have you tried printing them out?

Comment: @ignacio vazquez-abrams  I got it to work with the answer from irro, I do believe my code is pretty badly coded though and will cause me problems later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `regenerate_pin()` function doesn't see the `$newpin` variable and your UPDATE SQL might be wrong:

Change `"UPDATE pins SET pins='$newpin'"` to  `"UPDATE pins SET pin='$newpin'"`

For the function you have two options:

Add global $newpin; line inside the function regenerate_pin($pin) -code

```
function regenerate_pin($pin)
{  
 global $newpin;
...
}
```

or send the $newpin variable as an arbument to regenerate_pin-function.'

```
function regenerate_pin($pin, $newpin)
{  
...
}
```

and you have to call your regenerate_pin function like this

```
regenerate_pin('oldpin', 'newpin');
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, also if its ok I had to do this for it to work regenerate_pin($pin, $newpin); instead of regenerate_pin('oldpin', 'newpin');
but yeah should be working now, do I need to check for duplicates or is this highly unlikely? if so what do I need to do?

Comment: You should check for duplicates. I'd put an unique key to the pin fields 'alter table pins add unique key pin' so you will never have duplicate pins.  And you should change "SELECT pin FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1" to "SELECT pin FROM pins WHERE pin='$newpin' LIMIT 1" since you are checking does $newpin exsist.

Comment: It's currently working how I want it to @irro , except the fact that their could be duplicates, how would I add a unique key to the pin field? and its working with out your fix, I'm checking if $pin exists, if it does replace it with the a new pin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems i misunderstood.
But had better change:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
```

On

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(pin) FROM pins WHERE pin='$pin' LIMIT 1"));

if($result[0] == 0) {
```